# Why the data comes out from sklearn PCA multiple pca_components different from the original data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I am now trying to decomposition the data.

Here is my code:

```
import xlrd
import xlrd
import xlwt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = xlrd.open_workbook('x.xlsx')
sh=data.sheet_by_index(1)
num_rows = sh.nrows -1
num_cells = sh.ncols -1
inputData = np.empty([sh.nrows - 1, sh.ncols])
curr_row = -1
while curr_row < num_rows: # for each row
    curr_row += 1
    row = sh.row(curr_row)
    if curr_row > 0: # don't want the first row because those are labels
        for col_ind, el in enumerate(row):
            inputData[curr_row - 1, col_ind] = el.value

print(inputData.shape)
pca = PCA(n_components=3)
newData = pca.fit_transform(inputData)
print(inputData - np.dot(newData, pca.components_))
```

I think that the the difference between inputData and np.dot(newData, pca.components_) should be very small, but the thing is that the result seems far away from the original data.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the mean back. To do the reconstruction:

```
rec = np.dot(newData, pca.components_) + pca.mean_

print(inputData - rec)
```